# How to remove the "day" when the countdown clock is under 24 hours

Tags: javascript

I'd like the day numbers to disappear when the clock goes below 24 hours instead of having it read "00".

I've attempted a few solutions, but nothing seems to be working for me. I can attach the HTML/CSS if it is needed.

Here is my js:

```
    //
  (function(e){
        e.fn.countdown = function (t, n){
            function i(){
                eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
                currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
                //
                if(eventDate <= currentDate){
                    n.call(this);
                    clearInterval(interval)
                }
                //
                seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
                days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
                seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
                hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
                seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
                minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                seconds -= minutes * 60;
                //
                days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("Days") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("Days");
                hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("Hours") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("Hours");
                minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes");
                seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds");
                //
                if(r["format"] == "on"){
                    days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
                    hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
                    minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                    seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds
                }
                //
                if(!isNaN(eventDate)){
                    thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                    thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                    thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                    thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds)
                }
        else{
          errorMessage = "Invalid date. Example: 27 March 2015 17:00:00";
                    alert(errorMessage);
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                    clearInterval(interval)
                }
            }
            //
            var thisEl = e(this);
            var r = {
                date: null,
                format: null
            };
            //
            t && e.extend(r, t);
            i();
            interval = setInterval(i, 1e3)
        }
    })(jQuery);
    //
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function e(){
            var e = new Date;
            e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
            dd = e.getDate();
            mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
            y = e.getFullYear();
            futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
            return futureFormattedDate
        }
        //
        $("#countdown").countdown({
            date: "05 December 2019 14:00:00",
            format: "on"
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not really sure what other details I can provide, but please let me know if there is anything else I can submit to make this easier to answer.

Comment: The html would help, or at least the final output. What is the current output when there's less than a day?

Comment: So change the ternary to also deal with zero....

Comment: It sounds like you already did all the work in text? if (less than 24 hours) find and set text for "day" to an empty string?